# Why I can't update kernel version?

Tags: raspbian, kernel, update

I have perform the following command into ssh shell:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo reboot
```

But I still have an old kernel version, infact:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.10.25+ #622 PREEMPT Fri Jan 3 18:41:00 GMT 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Why my kernel is not updated? What am I missing? How can I solve?

Tnx

Comment: its `sudo apt-get update` *then* `sudo apt-get upgrade` you need to run - you then need to configure the Pi to use the new kernel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to [ https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware/commits/master ] and find the commit key for the version you want.

Then use the following command will update to the last version.

```
sudo rpi-update 81355451bcd9a214fdf221ca322b6ca681d8da55
```

Comment: mmm but why in the past days I updated it without execute this command simply using sudo apt-get upgrade and sudo apt-get update ? Have I simoly to use the last in time version of commit key in the website that you give me?

Comment: `sudo rpi-update` without any other parameters will update to the latest firmware.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn it happens to me that it will not update to the lates firmware with sudo rpi-update (I still in the same version)

Comment: `sudo rpi-update` is a different command than `sudo apt-get update`, are you doing rpi-update?  Your question doesn't show rpi-update.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn I'm not who asked this question, one time I made `sudo rpi-update` but still in the same version who is not the last one, so I had to specify the last commit to be updated