# Kernel version does not update when using apt update, apt full-upgrade

Tags: raspbian, kernel, apt, update, operating-systems

I want my Rpis to automatically update to the latest kernel pushed out by the Rpi Foundation, so I set up `unattended-upgrades`. I assume that's been working - but the kernel version hasn't updated since I installed the OS.

Hitting it with `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt full-upgrade` also doesn't get me the latest version of the released kernel. Just says there's no new updates.

I have an Rpi 2B and 3B running "Raspberry Pi OS Lite" and when I SSH in it says the Linux kernel is `5.4.51-v7+ #1333` (version I installed with). It's the default Debian Buster-based OS with minimal packages from https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/ . The current release is on `5.4.83`, per the website.

I can see from the release notes https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/release_notes.txt that the release is on `5.4.83`.

Following these (old) recommendations: [Why I can't update kernel version?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/17171/why-i-cant-update-kernel-version) , [How do I upgrade Raspbian?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4020/how-do-i-upgrade-raspbian) , [Stuck with the old kernel](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96443/stuck-with-the-old-kernel?rq=1)

I updated with `rpi-update` specifying the closest to `5.4.83` kernel on the site linked https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware/commits/master (`5.4.81`, 453e49bdd87325369b462b40e809d5f3187df21d).

That Rpi doesn't respond to SSH now, so that's not the way (update: it's now on `5.4.83` through manual reinstallation since it wasn't accessible and manually copying the `rpi-update` backups didn't fix it). I'd also like the kernel to update with `unattended-upgrades` anyway (and not have to rely on `rpi-update`). Also `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list` has `deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main` and I think that's right.

I've still got one Rpi ready to get bjorked, what am I missing? This seems like a basic thing that should "just work".

**Edit 3**

Upgraded the 2nd Rpi on `5.4.51` still to `unbootable`. Whoops that's linux for ya

I tried to get around that "not possible" error by the recommendation https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=275994#p1672308

`sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status`

[delete libraspberrypi0 libraspberrypi-bin libraspberrypi-dev libraspberrypi-doc raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel entries manually]

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

`sudo apt update; sudo apt install --reinstall libraspberrypi0 libraspberrypi-{bin,dev,doc} raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`

`sudo reboot`

Unfortunately though it did install the `5.4.83` kernel with those commands/file editing, the 2nd Rpi did not successfully boot after the reboot command. That's gonna get the same old reinstall, too.

So I'm not sure why `5.4.51` failed to update, but it looks like `5.4.83` will be able to update since my reinstalled Rpi running that responds without error to the `--reinstall` command. Will see on next release.

**Edit 2**

I tried `sudo apt install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel` on the reinstalled `5.4.83` Rpi and the command worked (obv nothing changed). But, on the old `5.4.51` Rpi it gives:

```
Reinstallation of raspberrypi-bootloader is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
Reinstallation of raspberrypi-kernel is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
```

Is this the crux of the problem? How do I circumvent this "not possible"?

**Edit**, here are the repo's the `5.4.51` Rpi hits:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian testing InRelease
```

The reinstalled Rpi on `5.4.83` has the added repo:

```
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
```

The testing branch is for wireguard, it was added with the code:

```
echo "deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian testing main" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list.d/testing.list
printf 'Package: *\nPin: release a=testing\nPin-Priority: 50\n' | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/preferences.d/limit-testing
```

per the guide for installing wireguard on `5.4.XX`-based Rpi's: https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/ha/wireguard/wireguard_02_en.html

Comment: Is that Raspbian Stretch, Raspbian Buster or RaspiOS Buster that you're running? Get a new SDCard and download the latest, then look at whether your old SDCard is end-of-life (and has gone read only).

Comment: It's now branded "Raspberry Pi OS" per https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/ but it's based on Debian Buster. Installed with that link the older `5.4.51` originally. The one I borked reinstalled just fine to the latest `5.4.83` but the 2nd one is still on `5.4.51` and `apt upgrade` won't get it. I edited the main Q with the repositories it's hitting, maybe it's missing one it needs to update? It's not SD card EOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happened again when kernel `5.10.17` was released, and I made a 2nd plea for help at [Kernel version does not update when using apt update, apt full-upgrade [again]](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/123646/kernel-version-does-not-update-when-using-apt-update-apt-full-upgrade-again/123766#123766). I managed to figure out what caused the issue and was able to upgrade from `5.4.83` to `5.10.17` successfully; same answer as that 2nd plea follows:

I backtracked commands and programs (deleting and unsetting settings) and trying `apt full-upgrade` each time until I hit what caused the `raspberry-kernel` to be removed from the upgrade list.

Turns out it was the testing branch for `wireguard` in Rpi kernel `5.4.XX`, it was added with the code:

```
echo "deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian testing main" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list.d/testing.list
printf 'Package: *\nPin: release a=testing\nPin-Priority: 50\n' | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/preferences.d/limit-testing
```

per the guide for installing `wireguard` on `5.4.XX`-based Rpi's: https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/ha/wireguard/wireguard_02_en.html

I deleted the entries in the `testing.list` and `limit-testing` and `raspberry-kernel` showed up in `apt full-upgrade`, added those entries back it and it disappeared.

I'm not sure why this caused an issue, since the `raspbian testing` repo had a low priority set so it wouldn't effect anything that was also in `main` repos. But I barely figured this out, so I won't try to divine what went wrongk in `apt`'s `raspberry-kernel` upgrade calculations.

Good news is that removing `wireguard` and the `testing` repo allowed for upgrading to the (currently) latest `5.10.17` kernel, and the `5.10.17` kernel has `wireguard` included in the kernel. You need to install `wireguard-tools` to use `wireguard` but `wireguard-tools` has been added to the main repos and can be installed with `sudo apt install wireguard-tools` without any repo shenanigans. This means that for future kernel upgrades I shouldn't have this issue since I don't have to use the `testing` branch anymore with the latest `5.10.17` kernel.