# Kernel version does not update when using apt update, apt full-upgrade [again]

Tags: update, raspberry-pi-os

Back again with the same issue (previously it was 5.4.51 -> 5.4.83 [Kernel version does not update when using apt update, apt full-upgrade](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120735/kernel-version-does-not-update-when-using-apt-update-apt-full-upgrade), got no useful suggestions) - now it's 5.4.83 -> 5.10.17. This is the moving from the [2nd latest RaspberryPiOS(c) release to the latest RaspberryPiOS release](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/).

Last time I ended up installing 5.4.83 fresh after börking the 5.4.51 trying to update linux on 2 Rpi's (2B and 3B) that are setup the same. I assume most people aren't having this issue since updating an OS shouldn't be this hard, even if it is Linux. I can get to 5.10.17 if I do a clean reinstall, but that's no way to live.

The obvious maneuver:

```
sudo reboot 
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Doesn't lead to an update:

```
Linux wiipii 5.4.83-v7+ #1379 SMP Mon Dec 14 13:08:57 GMT 2020 armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Mon Mar 29 23:19:32 2021 from 192.168.1.2
dmptrk@wiipii:~ $ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for dmptrk:
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian testing InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:4 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Hit:5 http://packages.azlux.fr/debian buster InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
dmptrk@wiipii:~ $ sudo apt full-upgrade
[sudo] password for dmptrk:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Last time I [tried `rpi-update`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120735/kernel-version-does-not-update-when-using-apt-update-apt-full-upgrade) and that bjorked the 3B, and [deleting the kernel-related entries](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=275994#p1672308) in `sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status` and then refreshing it and updating from there bonked the 2B. The SD cards are fine, the hardware is fine, if I wipe it and flash to 5.10.17 right now it'll work and I'll just have to set it all up again.

What can I do to update my rpis? What am I doing that's making it not work? I gotta be doing something to muck this up - but I'm not sure what or how to see what's going wrong.

*Note* I have `Hit:2 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian testing InRelease` as a repo to hit from adding Wireguard support per https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/ha/wireguard/wireguard_02_en.html 's

```
echo "deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian testing main" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list.d/testing.list
printf 'Package: *\nPin: release a=testing\nPin-Priority: 50\n' | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/preferences.d/limit-testing
```

The lower priority means it doesn't supersede anything that's in other repos, so it effects Wireguard and that's it. I understand 5.10 comes with Wireguard in the kernel and that'll be a great thing to deal with after updating to 5.10.

Comment: In a way, the answer here and there are identical! Had the same issue for 2 releases, 2nd time the [again] one figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I backtracked commands and programs (deleting and unsetting settings) and trying `apt full-upgrade` each time until I hit what caused the `raspberry-kernel` to be removed from the upgrade list.

Turns out it was the testing branch for `wireguard` in Rpi kernel `5.4.XX`, it was added with the code:

```
echo "deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian testing main" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list.d/testing.list
printf 'Package: *\nPin: release a=testing\nPin-Priority: 50\n' | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/preferences.d/limit-testing
```

per the guide for installing `wireguard` on `5.4.XX`-based Rpi's: https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/ha/wireguard/wireguard_02_en.html

I deleted the entries in the `testing.list` and `limit-testing` and `raspberry-kernel` showed up in `apt full-upgrade`, added those entries back it and it disappeared.

I'm not sure why this caused an issue, since the `raspbian testing` repo had a low priority set so it wouldn't effect anything that was also in `main` repos. But I barely figured this out, so I won't try to divine what went wrongk in `apt`'s `raspberry-kernel` upgrade calculations.

Good news is that removing `wireguard` and the `testing` repo allowed for upgrading to the (currently) latest `5.10.17` kernel, and the `5.10.17` kernel has `wireguard` included in the kernel. You need to install `wireguard-tools` to use `wireguard` but `wireguard-tools` has been added to the main repos and can be installed with `sudo apt install wireguard-tools` without any repo shenanigans. This means that for future kernel upgrades I shouldn't have this issue since I don't have to use the `testing` branch anymore with the latest `5.10.17` kernel.